# Inject Spring Bean as Endpoint with Jersey SpringServlet

Tags: jersey

Migrating a JAX-RS Service from CXF over to Jersey because of issues with WLS 12.

I currently have an Interface that has the JAX-RS annotations and then two classes that implement it (one being the class that fulfills the default functionality and one that is a stubbed implementation).

In CXF, I can use a property to drive which implementation class fulfills the ReST request through Spring injection:

```
   <alias name="restProxyApi${restProxyApi.sib:Impl}" alias="restProxyApiEndpoint" />

   <jaxrs:server id="jaxrs.restProxyApi" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="restProxyApiEndpoint" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
   </jaxrs:server>
```

I don't see a way to do this with Jersey.  Jersey seems to want me to use Spring's component scanning and declare the package that my API Endpoint existw in.  But this is not what I want to do. Is there a way in Jersey that I can utilize a Bean Id as the resource that Jersey uses to fulfill the request coming into the SpringServlet?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for solution of this issue a while as well. However, I think there's no such mechanism like interface,abstract class/implement which is often used with Spring IOC.

There's one way I can come up with is just don't bother worrying about the declaration and implementation on configuration of XMLs. But directly set your implementation class as a bean in Spring's beans.xml. For example:

There're two different implementations for the same Restful API, let's say RestA and RestB, and the code may look like...

```
@Path("/restApi")
public class RestA {
    @POST
    @Path("post/")
    public String print(@Context HttpServletRequest req, InputStream is) {
       // RestA: do something 
    }
}

@Path("/restApi")
public class RestB {
    @POST
    @Path("post/")
    public String print(@Context HttpServletRequest req, InputStream is) {
       // RestB: do something 
    }
}
```

Then, in your beans setting xml, just declare both of the class as beans for restful request, and mark one of them ... (here, the RestA handle request to http://x.x.x.x/restApi/post )

```
<beans>
    <bean id="restA" class="a.b.X.RestA" />
    <!-- <bean id="restB" class="a.b.y.RestB" /> -->
</beans>
```

And when you want to switch your restful API implementation, mark or remove the other beans.

Although this approach doesn't count as a real solution, it works for managing multiple implementations to the same restful api.